# fullcalendar datesRender

Tags: php, fullcalendar

In old version: this code will run properly

```
viewRender: function (view, element)
{
intervalStart = view.intervalStart;
intervalEnd = view.intervalEnd;
ctr += 1;
alert(intervalStart);
},
```

This code will alert the first day of the displayed month in the calendar.
How to do this in fullcalender v4? i have read that `viewRender` in version 3 is changed to `datesRender` with the parameters of info.

`viewRender` renamed to `datesRender`. Parameters have changed.

Comment: Please show us what you have done using the new version.

Comment: You seem to know what the changes are. So exactly what is stopping you from writing the code for the new version? Is there something specific you don't understand?

Comment: @adyson my code is lacking something but I've already solved the problem. Thanks